# Whatsapp calls: where are they logged?

Tags: iphone, ios, whatsapp.app

I am using an Iphone with iOS 8, and just installed the latest version of WhatsApp, which allows for voice calls from inside the app. Everything is fine... except that I don't see where are the calls logged. They don't appear in the calls log of the Phone app, nor there's any icon in that person's chat history. Where are they?

Comment: They may simply not be logged. (Note they will never appear in the Phone app - only calls made in the Phone app are logged there.)

Comment: If you set it UP--Whatsapp uses iCloud to back up not just text messages but also all incoming and outgoing media like photos, videos, and voice messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question: there's a new tab in Whatsapp called "Recent", which I hadn't paid attention to. It's the second one from the left, and it has the log of your recent Whatsapp voice calls.